# Probability transition function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

I am reading the following paper:
"http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142996313002"

We have the following definition:

> A function $p:X\times\mathcal{B}\mapsto[0,1]$ is a **stochastic transition function** if
>   1. $p(x,.)$ is a probability measure for every $x\in X$,
>   2. $p(.,A)$ is Lebesgue-measurable for every $A\in\mathcal{B}$

My question is from the following:
Let $\delta_y$ denote the Dirac measure supported on the point $y\in X$. Then $$p(x,A)=\delta_{h(x)}(A)$$ is a stochastic transition function for every $m$-measurable function $h$.

Note:

1. $f: X\mapsto X$ is a diffeomorphism on a compact subset $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$
3. $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}$

---

My question is $\delta_y$ only takes values $0$ or $1$; how does $p$ take for example the probability $0.3$? or How does it give the measure of an arbitrary subset $A\in \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: For a fixed $x$ and $A$, we have $p(x,A) = 1$ if $h(x) \in A$ and $p(x,A) = 0$ if $h(x) \notin A$. It cannot take the probability $0.3$ for any $x$ or $A$.

Comment: Aren't these just [Markov kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel)?

Comment: @goblin Oh, yes, or stochastic Kernel. I am just a bit confused about the $\delta$ function part in that article. Thanks for your remind